# Generic struct doesn't live long enough when passed to generic closure in function

Tags: generics, rust, closures, lifetime

I'm trying to write a simple utility function (to be used in tests) that wraps a given closure and exposes some database-related objects. It looks like this:

```rust
pub fn with_repository<'a, R, F>(f: F)
where
  R: Repository<'a>,
  F: FnOnce(R, &DbConnection),
{
  let connection = DbConnection::new();
  let repository = R::new(&connection);
  f(repository, &connection);
}
```

And here's how I plan to use it:

```rust
with_repository::<SomeRepository, _>(|_repository, _connection| {
  println!("Doing stuff with repository or the connection..");
});
```

Now this gives me the famous error `E0597 - borrowed value does not live long enough`:

```
error[E0597]: `connection` does not live long enough
  --> src/utils/test.rs:50:27
   |
44 | pub fn with_repository<'a, R, F>(f: F)
   |                        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
50 |   let repository = R::new(&connection);
   |                    -------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                    |      |
   |                    |      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                    argument requires that `connection` is borrowed for `'a`
51 |   f(repository, &connection);
52 | }
   | - `connection` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I would really like to understand what's causing the issue here. Is it because `f` could theoretically pass the ownership of `repository` to another scope? That would kind of make sense, but I've tried changing the closure to take `&R` instead and nothing changed. I've also tried a lot of different ways to annotate the lifetime, but now I'm just guessing.

Here's a link to the playground with a "working" example: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=struct%20DbConnection%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Repository%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new(connection%3A%20%26%27a%20DbConnection)%20-%3E%20Self%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20UserRepository%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20db%3A%20%26%27a%20DbConnection%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Repository%3C%27a%3E%20for%20UserRepository%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new(db%3A%20%26%27a%20DbConnection)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%20%7B%20db%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20with_repository%3CR%2C%20F%3E(f%3A%20F)%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20for%3C%27a%3E%20R%3A%20Repository%3C%27a%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20F%3A%20FnOnce(R%2C%20%26DbConnection)%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20connection%20%3D%20DbConnection%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20repository%20%3D%20R%3A%3Anew(%26connection)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20f(repository%2C%20%26connection)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20with_repository%3A%3A%3CUserRepository%2C%20_%3E(%7C_repository%2C%20_connection%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Doing%20stuff%20with%20repository%20or%20the%20connection..%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)

**EDIT 1**: Okay immediately after posting the question I thought of another possible solution and it worked:

```rust
pub fn with_repository<R, F>(f: F)
where
  for<'a> R: Repository<'a>,
  F: FnOnce(R, &DbConnection),
{
  let connection = DbConnection::new();
  let repository = R::new(&connection);
  f(repository, &connection);
}
```

However, I would still appreciate an explanation of why it didn't work in the first place - what's the difference between specifying the lifetime in the function signature and in the `for` clause?

**EDIT 2**: Turns out it doesn't work after all. It's now giving this mysterious error (see playground for more details):

```
error: implementation of `Repository` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:5
   |
3  | / trait Repository<'a> {
4  | |     fn new(connection: &'a DbConnection) -> Self;
5  | | }
   | |_- trait `Repository` defined here
...
28 |       with_repository::<UserRepository, _>(|_repository, _connection| {
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `Repository` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `Repository<'0>` would have to be implemented for the type `UserRepository<'_>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `Repository<'1>` is actually implemented for the type `UserRepository<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

Comment: Why are you passing an immutable reference of a `DbConnection` to a `Repository`? Why not just pass ownership?

Comment: It's because the repository actually contains another connection reference inside, so it wouldn't work - I've updated the playground to show it.

Comment: What do you mean "the repository actually contains _another_ connection reference inside"? In your playground example a `Repository` only contains the single `DbConnection` reference it's created with. It's still not clear why you're passing a reference instead of ownership.

Comment: You're probably right and I misunderstood an error that I got at some point when I tried to move it instead of passing a reference. Still though, removing the reference doesn't seem to solve anything (it actually raises another error - `cannot move out of "connection" because it is borrowed`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Generic parameters are chosen by the caller. This function signature:

```rust
fn with_repository<'a, R, F>(f: F)
where
    R: Repository<'a>,
    F: FnOnce(R, &DbConnection),
{
    let connection = DbConnection {};
    let repository = R::new(&connection);
    f(repository, &connection);
}
```

Would allow users to call your function like this:

```rust
with_repository<'static, UserRepository<'static>, _>(|repo, conn| {});
```

Which would require the function to produce a `&'static DbConnection` which is not possible. Even if you move the `'a` from the function signature to the trait bound:

```rust
fn with_repository<R, F>(f: F)
where
    R: for<'a> Repository<'a>,
    F: FnOnce(R, &DbConnection),
{
    let connection = DbConnection {};
    let repository = R::new(&connection);
    f(repository, &connection);
}
```

Users would still be able to call your function like this:

```rust
with_repository<UserRepository<'static>, _>(|repo, conn| {});
```

So the underlying problem remains (even though the compiler error has changed).

The only approaches we can take toward solving this problem are to either get rid of the references entirely or to pass the references from outside of the function (instead of constructing them from inside the function). Since the former isn't possible for your use-case that only leaves us with the latter:

```rust
fn with_repository<'a, R, F>(connection: &'a DbConnection, f: F)
where
    R: Repository<'a>,
    F: FnOnce(R, &DbConnection),
{
    let repository = R::new(connection);
    f(repository, connection);
}
```

Then you can call it from unit tests like this:

```rust
fn some_test() {
    let connection = DbConnection;
    with_repo::<UserRepository, _>(&connection, |repository, connection| {
        // work with repository & connection here
    });
}
```

Although that's just a pointlessly verbose version of doing this which is much cleaner and more concise:

```rust
fn some_test() {
    let connection = DbConnection;
    let repository = UserRepository::new(&connection);
    // work with repository & connection here
}
```

If constructing the `connection` in your real code is laborious I would abstract that into its own function so the boilerplate at the beginning of your tests stays lean:

```rust
fn get_test_connection() -> DbConnection {
    // construct and return connection here
}

fn some_test() {
    let connection = get_test_connection();
    let repository = UserRepository::new(&connection);
    // work with repository & connection here
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure that would work and I'm sorry for not being more clear in my question but I'm actually forced to keep a reference in the `Repository` object. This is because in the application code I have only one connection but there can be multiple Repository instances that need to reference it (and because `DbConnection` isn't `Clone`).

Comment: If you have only a single `DbConnection` in your entire app then where does it "live"? Surely it doesn't make sense to create it from inside the `with_repository` function if you need it be accessible from the rest of your entire app?

Comment: That's right, normally these connections are being stored in a connection pool and I'm passing them as references down the stack. However, this simple utility function is meant to be used in tests - here I don't really care where this connection is being stored (here it's stored in the function itself because I don't need it after the closure is finished), but I can't change the code that's being used in the "real" app (in this case the Repository trait).

Comment: I did some more research and investigation into this problem and I'm afraid the answer is it's not possible. I updated my answer with a more detailed explanation and also with some alternative suggestions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It's unfortunate that it can't be done but your suggestions are really helpful.